# put some space in xAxis labels & merge duplicate labels chartjs

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I am using chartjs to create a line graph and its working fine, I am facing few problems, I have got the line graph like that in picture
[image]

the issue I am facing is, I need to merge the same dates with each other, as you can see in the image, `2017-10-12` is multiple times, 
here is my config

```
  var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: labelsZchartjs,
      datasets: [{
        label: " % Allowance Used",
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: chartColors.blue,
        borderColor: chartColors.blue,
        data: dataZChartsJS,
      }]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          boxWidth: 0,
          fontStyle: "bold",
          fontSize: 20
        }
      },
      responsive: true,
      tooltips: {
        bodyFontStyle: "bold",
        mode: 'label',
      },
      hover: {
        mode: 'nearest',
        intersect: true
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
              autoSkip : true,
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                return new moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
              }
          },
          display: true,
          fontStyle: "bold",
          scaleLabel: {
            fontStyle: "bold",
            display: false,
            labelString: 'Date & Time'
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              stepSize: 10
          },
          display: true,
          fontStyle: "bold",
          scaleLabel: {
            fontStyle: "bold",
            display: true,
            labelString: '% Allowance Used'
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  };
```

I am looking for a suggestion or way to make it more accurate with one date for one day, or as on the same date there are multiple Y-axis values, so cant we get the mean of all values in one day? or anything, which may make this graph better, any help will be appreciable.
the data is in this format

```
[{percentage_used: 0.012, datetime: "2017-09-28 05:50:43"}
{percentage_used: 0.028, datetime: "2017-10-10 05:02:47"}
{percentage_used: 0.028, datetime: "2017-10-10 17:11:01"}
{percentage_used: 0.029, datetime: "2017-10-11 04:37:42"}
{percentage_used: 0.029, datetime: "2017-10-11 12:49:53"}]
```

Comment: Hi! Soo my suggestion is that you can process those dates in order to put it together when they have the same x value(in this case a date). To do this you need to choose some chart that can have multiple y values for the same x value (e.g. scatter https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2/issues/358). Here: you have 1 more example:
https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/docs/howto-display-date-time-values-on-a-scatter-chart.html